# Java Implementation of JsonLogic Not Working

Tags: java, boolean-logic

Has anyone successfully used the [Java implementation](https://github.com/deinspanjer/json-logic-java) of [JsonLogic](http://jsonlogic.com/)?

This rule

```
{"==" : [ { "var" : "code" }, "ER"]}
```

gives the correct answer (true) with this data

```
{"code": "ER", "name": "Exploratory Research"}
```

using the [javascript playground](http://jsonlogic.com/play.html).

However, this Java code

```
JavaJsonLogic jsonLogic = JavaJsonLogic.INSTANCE;
String rule = "{\"==\" : [ { \"var\" : \"code\" }, \"ER\"]}";
JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
data.addProperty("code", "ER");
data.addProperty("name", "Exploratory Research")
System.out.println(jsonLogic.apply(rule, data)););
```

returns `false`!

Comment: I haven't used this library before but just to rule this out, is `component` actually supposed to be `data`? You `addProperty` to `component`, but then use `data` in the last line. Is this a typo for the post or is this what your code is doing as well?

Comment: Sorry! Yes 'component' should be 'data'. Typo is in in post only.

Comment: This is an abandoned library, use this one instead
https://github.com/meiskalt7/json-logic-java

It fully supports the JsonLogic standard.
All official tests were successfully passed.

Answer (score 2):

```
        JsonLogic jsonLogic = new JsonLogic();
        String rule = "{\"==\" : [ { \"var\" : \"code\" }, \"ER\"]}";
        //JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("name", "Exploratory Research");
        data.put("code", "ER");
        jsonLogic.apply(rule, data);
```

I am using a hashmap to populate value in place of `JsonObject`. And the result is coming out as true. And also i am using `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jamsesso` for parsing jsonLogic string and validating the data over jsonlogic.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes accross this problem, better late than never :)

I had the same problem with my code. I needed to access a property of an object in a list, inside of an object.

You have to convert your object to a map, and this worked for me, reference here https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-object-to-map:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper
      .convertValue(employee, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
jsonLogic.apply(rule, map);
```

In the source code of JsonLogic for java, there is a check to see if it's an instance of a Map:

```
if (data instanceof Map) {
  return transform(((Map) data).get(key));
}
```

this put me on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

dmillerw too did the jsonlogic implementation for java based off of jsonlogic spec that you were following. I just tried by picking up the code base from below URL and with your test data, it is working like a charm.

https://github.com/dmillerw/json-logic-java

Here is what I had in my junit to test your need:

```
    String testjson = **"[[{\"==\" : [ { \"var\" : \"code\" }, \"ER\"]},{\"code\": \"ER\", \"name\": \"Exploratory Research\"},true]]";**
    JsonArray testArray = gson.fromJson(testjson, JsonArray.class);

    for (JsonElement element : testArray) {
        JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonElement test = array.get(0);
        JsonElement data = array.get(1);
        JsonElement expected = array.get(2);
        System.out.println(**JsonLogic.apply(test, data)**);
```

}

Comment: @Zoe Please find the detail